# (c++) Reading numeric data in a column from a txt file and determining highest value

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a program that will read a txt file where time, voltage and ampere are stored, the text file looks like this http://pastebin.com/a0ZvYGmj, only ten times bigger (it's obnoxiously huge, so large that it didn't fit into a single pastebin).

So what I have to do is write a program that will read through the entire voltage column and detect the highest value (second column), then display it and the time it occurs (first column). I can also do it with the ampere, but that's optional.

Problem is I literally have no idea what to do, this is what I have managed to do so far

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
FILE * pFile;
char mystring [100];

pFile = fopen ("voltage.txt" , "r");
if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
else {
  if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
   puts (mystring);
 fclose (pFile);
}

 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

But all that does is read the first entry of each of the 3 columns ("Time Volt Ampere"), so I probably have to start over.

Can anyone send me in the right direction? How do I read an entire column, them make the program detect the biggest number in said column?

I'm completely lost so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sure you want C++ for this?  gnu `sort`, for one, is specialized in exactly this (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort)!

Comment: Do you need to write a C++ program, or do you need to process your text file and happen to want to do it in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the option of using the file as an input, then you could use simple cin in order to get your values for Time,Volt and Amp. ( the only thing you need to keep in mind is to ignore first row because they are just names)

If you know that all three values in each row will be present, then you can create while loop that runs until EOF.  Then you read 3 values (Time, Volt, Amp) and compare with the previous Volt. 
If previous volt is larger - ignore this row and move on. 
Else - keep current Time, Volt and Amp.

On the next iteration, compare new 3 values to the max value of Volt so far.

Here is my "quick and dirty" solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// cin>>temp goes through names and ignores it since we don't need it
string temp;
cin >> temp;
cin >> temp;
cin >> temp;

float timeval = 0;
float volt = 0;
float amp = 0;
float timevalTemp = 0;
float voltTemp = 0;
float ampTemp = 0;

while(cin >> timevalTemp >> voltTemp >> ampTemp)
{
    if(voltTemp > volt)
    {
        timeval = timevalTemp;
        volt = voltTemp;
        amp = ampTemp;
    }
}
cout << "Max Time: " << timeval << endl;
cout << "Max Volt: " << volt << endl;
cout << "Max Amp: "<< amp << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Let me know if something is not clear. I ran it on your text file and it produces:

```
Max Time: 0.00035
Max Volt: 9.78167
Max Amp: 0.1473
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to do, but I don't see it opens any file, how did you run this on the text file? Thank you for your help

Comment: @user3018180 I compiled the code. Then in console, write :
./program < inputfile.txt

cin tries to get input from the user, if you don't provide input file, it will prompt you to input values. Otherwise, it uses the file and runs until (cin>>time...) fails in while loop

Comment: @user3018180 IMO this way a bit better, since you don't have to hardcode the name of the file and you can use your code on different files, when testing. But that is only my preference.

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried it but I get 0 for every variable.

The source file is in the same directory as the txt file, what am I doing wrong? Could it be that the txt file is too large?

Comment: Did you run my code and got wrong answer? weird...
Make sure that executable file and the textInputfile are in the same directory. I used the file you provided and it works for me.  Unless the format of other input files that use is different, I don't see how you can get different answer than me. :S

Comment: (./program < voltage.txt)

That's the command I have to input in the console right? both the executable and txt file are in the same directory, yet I always get 0.

And yes I'm using your code, didn't change anything other than the text file name.

Comment: I use Cygwin on Win7 machine(but that should not change the outcome). Are you compiling it in the same way? :
`g++ findMax.cpp -o findMax`


`./findMax < findMaxInput.txt`

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ 5.3.0.4 on a Win7 machine. I'll try using Cygwin and see how it does.

Comment: I am not familiar with Dev-C++ IDE. I use Cygwin for compiling in Unix-like Terminal window. 
Try installing Cygwin or find a way to add input file inside Dev-C++.

Comment: Oh damn, I have absolutely no clue how to use cygwin, I'm still a very, VERY inexperienced programmer, I have no idea how to use an environment like this.

I'll try finding a way to make the program open the input file in Dev-C++, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Also if I read from a file instead of opening one, do I need to change any code in the program you wrote? cin commands maybe?

Comment: If you provide a filename as input, when running your code, then I don't think you need to change anything. Cin will read from input you provided. As to using Cygwin, I think it is very useful because it provides UNIX like terminal. Install it and find some tutorials on it. It is not as complicated as you think, but it will add value to your development skills :) (IMHO, once again)
If you find the answer useful and/or correct, please mark it accordingly :)

Comment: How do I add a filename as an input? Assuming the textfile I'm using is named "voltage.txt", where and how do I open the file so the rest of the program uses it instead of waiting for input in the console?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you don't want to provide input in console, you may open file using streams.  Try to google it and see some samples either on StackOverflow or some other places. Here is a link that helps with dev-c++ IDE : [link](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~paulp/CS215S05/CS215DevCPPComments.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fscanf. Please have a look at this [How to use fscanf to read a file](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/150654-using-fscanf-read-text-file.html)

After you read you will have to compare voltage values of each row to get max voltage. I hope you know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use a llop construction so you read the whole set of lines. So try putting your `fgets`inside of a `while`.

Next, you need to split each line by spaces. Use `strtok`for that.

Next I'll recommend you keep a `max_voltage` variable and as you travel through the file, you assign it the current max value. Also, you need to keep track of that `max_voltage` variable's `time`companion so use another variable for that one (Google for "find max value in an array" if you have doubts about how to do it).

After you try that, post your work if you have some question/need clarifications.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

fgets reads file untill it encounter newline character, or end of file.

If fgets encounters eof before any character it'll return null pointer. So it should be okay if you change file reading code to:

```
while ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
  puts (mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define what a line looks like:

```
struct Line {
  double time, volt, ampere;
  int linenumber;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Line& line) {
    ++linenumber;
    return in >> line.time >> line.volt >> line.ampere;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Line& line) {
  return out << "Line: " << line.linenumber 
             << " Time: " << line.time 
             << " Volt: " << line.volt 
             << " Ampere: " << line.ampere;
}
```

and use it with `std::cin`.

```
int main()
{
    string dummy;
    std::istream& in = cin;
    in >> dummy >> dummy >> dummy;
    Line max;
    Line line;
    while(in.good()) {
        in >> line;
        if (line.volt > max.volt) max = line;
    }
   cout << "Max line: " << max;
   return 0;
}
```

(or you can replace `cin` with a file input stream:

```
#include <ifstream>
...
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    ...
```

)

Comment: Tried it, I get the following:

"Max line: Time 0 Volt 4.34372e-311 Ampere: 0"

Damn why is this text file so hard to read?

Comment: Probably, you want a little more insight in your text file.  Add line numbers, or so... (note how this doesn't change the while-loop!)

Comment: The thing is I can't change the text file, I have to make a program that reads it the way it is.

Comment: Of course, but I think your text file contains some anomalies here and there.  Either you pre-process it, or you make your program more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sort`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) for that, it's a highly specialized merge-sort implementation that surely included in your cygwin distro.  You can tell it which columns to sort on (the -k switch), and it both works with stdandard input and filename.

Then just take e.g. the first 4 lines of output to account for 'special' lines.  Use `cat -n` to prepend line numbers.

```
$ cat -n input.txt | sort -r -k 2  | head -n 10
     1  Time    Volt    Ampere
  4796  0.2398  9.76417 0.147683
  4795  0.23975 9.75667 0.147833
  4794  0.2397  9.77333 0.147867
  4793  0.23965 9.7575  0.14765
  4792  0.2396  9.75167 0.147533
  4791  0.23955 9.75833 0.147542
  4790  0.2395  9.75583 0.147542
  4789  0.23945 9.77    0.1476
  4788  0.2394  9.75583 0.147317
```